# Android: how to use Rsync in own app?

Tags: java, android, rsync

Is there any Rsync API or other way  to use it in own app, without direct user interaction?

Comment: the solution is here http://vidar.botfu.org/android-ase-and-rsync

Comment: possible duplicate of [Any good rsync library for Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1246255/any-good-rsync-library-for-java)

Comment: I've got rsync binary but can't exec it. Help!!! Where should i put it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use rsync you need to download it binaries http://rsync.samba.org/download.html and read this "how can I put my own native executable in Android App?" http://gimite.net/en/index.php?Run%20native%20executable%20in%20Android%20App#hddd196e